# Getting url of child tab in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is about java script issue. I'd like to get url of child tab in chrome browser. 
I'm using below code for testing,

```
<script>    
var child = window.open('https://www.google.co.kr/', 'child', 'width=300, height=300');
console.dir(child.document);
setInterval(function(){ console.dir(child.document);}, 3000);
</script>
```

But...below error comes up. Could you please why this matter comes up??
If you have another solution for getting url info, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use `child.location.href`?

Comment: Also, don't use tags that are entirely irrelevant to the question (java)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I approved it. and child.location.href give me a message "blank". I think this issue is concerned CORS.

Comment: you cannot if [domains don't match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Otherwise this would be a serious security issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks a lot !! I guess....this issue is concerned CORS.. so I solved this issue using ajax.